# Can't edit remote file with VIM

Tags: macos, vim, scp

I'm trying to edit a remote file with VIM. In terminal, I type:

```
vim scp://my_user@some.server.net//app/logs/jboss/sso.log
```

and get this output:

```
:!scp -q 'my_user@some.server.net:/app/logs/jboss/sso.log' '/var/folders/4d/6z5mf6m96bq105stbqy_tjf4jmvwpj/T/vyHJPX5/0.log'
my_user@some.server.net's password:

[8]+  Stopped                 vim scp://my_user@some.server.net//app/logs/jboss/sso.log
```

I know that I have the right credentials and the file exists, because:

```
scp my_user@some.server.net:/app/logs/jboss/sso.log ~/Documents
```

successfully copies the desired file to localhost.
The [vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Editing_remote_files_via_scp_in_vim) suggests that my syntax is correct.

The file is being downloaded, but VIM doesn't start to edit it.
The same happens when I start vim and issue the following command:

`:e scp://my_user@some.server.net//app/logs/jboss/sso.log`

The file is downloaded to the temp folder, and I'm being thrown out of VIM back to the console.

I'm using VIM 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov  6 2014 14:32:04) on OSX. I installed it with brew.

How can I fix this situation and have VIM started to edit the remote file?

Comment: I believe, preferred way is to connect to remote and edit it in remote vim (if it is installed there), like this: `ssh -tt my_user@some.server.net vim /app/logs/jboss/sso.log`

Comment: @Jakuje: This is how I do it at the moment, but I'd like to use a local instance of vim because I want to use my custom key bindings and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Vim is trying to create a temporary local copy of your file for the editing. But this is located at `/var/folders/...` (as shown in the `scp`), which you may not have permissions to write to.

Try having it write somewhere your user controls by setting `TMPDIR`:

```
export TMPDIR=$HOME/tmp
mkdir $TMPDIR  # if it doesn't exist
```

Also, by having the double-slash (`//`), you’re telling vim to use an absolute path, so `/app` should not be relative to `my_user`’s home. Not clear if you’re doing that intentionally.

Comment: I'm using absolute path on purpose. After updating the `TMPDIR` I don't see the `[8]+ Stopped ...` message, but VIM does not start. I'm able to put some characters in the console and pressing Enter puts me in a new line. After pressing `^c` I can see the `[8]+ Stopped...` message again.

Comment: I'm not sure what is triggering the "stopped" message. Make sure your $TMPDIR exists.

Comment: I made sure the `$TMPDIR` exists and set access rights to `777`. The problem still occurs as described in my previous comment.